# Find even numbers from list box1 and display in list box2 also display odd numbers in list box3

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a button that generates 20 random numbers in listbox1. I am stuck on figuring out how to find even numbers from the list and put them in listbox2 then do the same for odd numbers in listbox3

Here's what I have so far but is wrong. When running the solution I just get a list of numbers in order from 0-20:

```
 int i = 0;



if(i % 2 == 0)

 {

 for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)

 {

}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Usage guidance from the Visual Studio tag: *`Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio...`*

Answer (score 1):

This will add the even numbers in listbox1 to listbox2, and odd numbers from listbox1 into listbox3:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listbox1.Items.Count; i ++)
{
   if(Convert.ToInt64(listbox1.Items[i]) % 2 == 0)
   {
      listbox2.Items.Add(listbox1.Items[i])
   }
   else
   {
      listbox3.Items.Add(listbox1.Items[i])
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).